# GLSL calculating color vector from multiple lights

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm using my own (not opengl built in) light. This is my fragment shader program:

```
#version 330

in vec4 vertexPosition;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec2 textureCoordinate;
in vec3 eyeVecNormal;

out vec4 outputColor;

uniform sampler2D texture_diffuse;
uniform bool specular;
uniform float shininess;

struct Light {
    vec4 position;
    vec4 ambientColor;
    vec4 diffuseColor;
    vec4 specularColor;
};

uniform Light lights[8];

void main()
{
    outputColor = texture2D(texture_diffuse, textureCoordinate);
    for (int l = 0; l < 8; l++) {
        vec3 lightDirection = normalize(lights[l].position.xyz - vertexPosition.xyz);
        float diffuseLightIntensity = max(0, dot(surfaceNormal, lightDirection));

        outputColor.rgb += lights[l].ambientColor.rgb * lights[l].ambientColor.a;
        outputColor.rgb += lights[l].diffuseColor.rgb * lights[l].diffuseColor.a * diffuseLightIntensity;
        if (specular) {
            vec3 reflectionDirection = normalize(reflect(lightDirection, surfaceNormal));
            float specular = max(0.0, dot(eyeVecNormal, reflectionDirection));
            if (diffuseLightIntensity != 0) {
                vec3 specularColorOut = pow(specular, shininess) * lights[l].specularColor.rgb;
                outputColor.rgb += specularColorOut * lights[l].specularColor.a;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, that when i have 2 light sources with say ambient color `vec4(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f)` the ambient color on model will be `vec4(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f)` because i simply add it to the outputColor variable. **How can i calculate a single ambient and a single diffuse color variables for multiple lights, so i would get a realistic result?**

Comment: Ambient is a hack anyway, standing in for reflected light... so you can pretty much do whatever you want - Why not just make ambient a property of your scene rather than per-light?

Comment: You probably want to attenuate the intensity of the light, given its distance from the fragment. Have a look at the formulae that the fixed function pipeline uses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a fun fact: lights in the real world do not have ambient, diffuse, or specular colors. They emit *one* color. Period (OK, if you want to be technical, lights emit *lots* of colors. But individual photons don't have "ambient" properties. They just have different wavelengths). All you're doing is copying someone who copied OpenGL's nonsense about ambient and diffuse light colors.

Stop copying someone else's code and do it *right*.

Each light has a color. You use that color to compute the diffuse and specular contributions of that light to the object. That's it.

Ambient is a property of the *scene*, not of any particular light. It is intended to represent [indirect, global illumination](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Illumination/Tut09%20Global%20Illumination.html): the light reflected from other objects in the scene, as taken as a general aggregate. You don't have ambient "lights"; there is only one ambient term, and it should be applied once.